Can I use anchor address constraint with dynamic value from state
Here is the example of how address constraint is implemented, but the address is CONSTANT
https://beta.solpg.io/66b37272cffcf4b13384d2aa
I want to be able to change the authority who signs the transaction. How to specify the state variable of the program in the address constraint?
EDIT:
I didn’t find such examples, but I found this:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Create<'info> {
   #[account(init, payer = user, owner = signer.key(), space = 8 + 40 )]
    pub signer_account: Account<'info, SignerAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

So maybe I can add an address constraint to “signer_account” with constant address and later change the owners of this signer_account and require them to be signers?
